# Error when attempting to startup Mongod after installing MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I get the following error whenever I try to run Mongod on my Mac with Catalina:

```
2020-04-27T18:18:15.100+0100 I  CONTROL  [main] Automatically disabling TLS 1.0, to force-enable TLS 1.0 specify --sslDisabledProtocols 'none'
2020-04-27T18:18:15.108+0100 W  ASIO     [main] No TransportLayer configured during NetworkInterface startup
2020-04-27T18:18:15.108+0100 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=1345 port=27017 dbpath=/data/db 64-bit host=Jonathans-MacBook-Pro.local
2020-04-27T18:18:15.109+0100 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version v4.2.6
2020-04-27T18:18:15.109+0100 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] git version: 20364840b8f1af16917e4c23c1b5f5efd8b352f8
2020-04-27T18:18:15.109+0100 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] allocator: system
2020-04-27T18:18:15.109+0100 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] modules: none
2020-04-27T18:18:15.109+0100 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] build environment:
2020-04-27T18:18:15.109+0100 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distarch: x86_64
2020-04-27T18:18:15.109+0100 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten]     target_arch: x86_64
2020-04-27T18:18:15.109+0100 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: {}
2020-04-27T18:18:15.109+0100 E  NETWORK  [initandlisten] Failed to unlink socket file /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock Permission denied
2020-04-27T18:18:15.109+0100 F  -        [initandlisten] Fatal Assertion 40486 at src/mongo/transport/transport_layer_asio.cpp 684
2020-04-27T18:18:15.109+0100 F  -        [initandlisten] 

***aborting after fassert() failure
```

I have done everything on every guide to install Mongo, I've allowed the permissions, and I've created all of the necessary files.

Can somebody please advise how I can fix this?

Answer (score 1):

This error:

```
Failed to unlink socket file /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock Permission denied
```

indicates that the service is attempting to remove a socket file, most likely to create new one for the new service, but the user that the mongod is running as does not have permission to delete `/tmp/mongodb-27017.sock`.

Make sure there are no other mongod processes running and then delete  `/tmp/mongodb-27017.sock` manually.